# Не удается открыть порты 8080 и все другие на AWS EC2

Tags: настройка, amazon-web-services, ec2

Всем привет, не удается открыть порты 8080 и все другие, на AWS EC2, установлена ubuntu, в security group выставлены полный доступ для всех на порт 8080, все файерволы в убунте отключены(ufw,iptables не активный), но порт закрыт и все...только два порта работают 22, 80, подскажите пожалуйста что я не так сделал?

Answer (score 1):

Действия следующие:

1. Посмотреть какая Security Group установлена для данного ec2 instace (**EC2 Dashboard->Instaces**).
2. Для этой Security Group (**EC2 Dashboard->Security Groups**) добавить и сохранить inbound rule такого содержания:
   **Custom TCP Rule TCP 8080 Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0**
3. Затем уже по ssh зайти на instace. Если установлен web-server apache - то править следующий конфигурационный файл: **/etc/apache2/ports.conf**. Добавить в него строчку 
   **Listen 8080**.
4. Перезапустить apache: **sudo service apache2 restart**
5. Убедиться что порт добавлен: 
   **netstat -lntup**

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, разобрался оказывается просто никто не слушал порт, а на сайтах проверки портов, выходит что порт закрыт, на самом деле она просто не умеют распознавать когда порт закрыт и когда его никто не слушает..

Comment: @StateItPrimitive нет, это был именно ответ на вопрос.